# How to use .swf in c# with Transparent background

Tags: c#, wpf, flash, wpf-controls

> is there's a way  to use flash file inside WPF c# application with Transparent  back ground ?  i tried this

```
  public  Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        getdata();
        SetStyle(ControlStyles.SupportsTransparentBackColor, true);
        axShockwaveFlash1.Movie = @"c:\users\ahmed\documents\visual studio 2013\Projects\WindowsFormsApplication1\WindowsFormsApplication1\loading10.swf";
        axShockwaveFlash1.Play();


    }
```

> and this

```
            axShockwaveFlash1.BackgroundColor =0;
```

> and many below ! any idea ? i still get back color behind the file .

Comment: Try to set the `wmode` property to `transparent`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't do it by code at runtime.

**Solution** : Set (`WMode`) transparency via menu in the component settings (in Designer).

Find similar options to as shown in VB picture below:

[image]